Show and hide images using dropdown (js , html)
Was  trying to make a multipurpose calendar application
Currently i only need fron August...


$('#aug').hide
$('#sep').hide
$('#oct').hide
$('#nov').hide
$('#dec').hide

function aug() {
  $('#aug').show
  $('#sep').hide
  $('#oct').hide
  $('#nov').hide
  $('#dec').hide
}

function sep() {
  $('#aug').hide
  $('#sep').show
  $('#oct').hide
  $('#nov').hide
  $('#dec').hide
}

function oct() {
  $('#aug').hide
  $('#sep').hide
  $('#oct').show
  $('#nov').hide
  $('#dec').hide
}

function nov() {
  $('#aug').hide
  $('#sep').hide
  $('#oct').hide
  $('#nov').show
  $('#dec').hide
}

function dec() {
  $('#aug').hide
  $('#sep').hide
  $('#oct').hide
  $('#nov').hide
  $('#dec').show
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="page-1" id="page-1">
  <div class="calender" id="calender">
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value="">Jan</option>
      <option value="">Feb</option>
      <option value="">Mar</option>
      <option value="">Apr</option>
      <option value="">May</option>
      <option value="">Jun</option>
      <option value="">Jul</option>
      <option value="">Aug</option>
      <option value="">Sep</option>
      <option value="">Oct</option>
      <option value="">Nov</option>
      <option value="">Dec</option>
    </select>
    <div id="img-grp" class="img-grp">
      <img src="" alt="Jan" id="Jan">
      <img src="" alt="Feb" id="Feb">
      <img src="" alt="Mar" id="mar">
      <img src="" alt="Apr" id="Apr">
      <img src="" alt="May" id="may">
      <img src="" alt="Jun" id="jun">
      <img src="" alt="Jul" id="jul">
      <img src="months-png/aug.png" alt="Aug" onclick="aug()" id="aug">
      <img src="months-png/sep.png" alt="Sep" onclick="sep()" id="sep">
      <img src="months-png/oct.png" alt="Oct" onclick="oct()" id="oct">
      <img src="months-png/nov.png" alt="Nov" onclick="nov()" id="nov">
      <img src="months-png/dec.png" alt="Dec" onclick="dec()" id="dec">
    </div>
  </div>




I tried using jquery, $('#aug').hide
but it just gave
the page

can anyone pls help
there are also some extra code  which shows the time and more images...
more details : it is running locally, and have no plans to host..
according to visual studio code , there are no problems in the code...
google chrome also says there are no problems inn the code., Atleast it doesnt show up in the console
full code:

<script src="JQuery(nonLicenced).js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f4453c02b1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="main" id="top-section">
    <div class="page-0" id="page-0">
        <p class="Clock" id="p1"></p>
        <p class="date" id="p2">susu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="page-1" id="page-1">
        <div class="calender" id="calender">
            <select name="" id="calender-select">
                <option value="">Jan</option>
                <option value="">Feb</option>
                <option value="">Mar</option>
                <option value="">Apr</option>
                <option value="">May</option>
                <option value="">Jun</option>
                <option value="">Jul</option>
                <option value="" >Aug</option>
                <option value=""  >Sep</option>
                <option value="" >Oct</option>
                <option value="" >Nov</option>
                <option value=""  >Dec</option>
            </select>
            <div id="img-grp" class="img-grp">
                <img src="" alt="Jan" id="Jan">
                <img src="" alt="Feb" id="Feb">
                <img src="" alt="Mar" id="mar">
                <img src="" alt="Apr" id="Apr">
                <img src="" alt="May" id="may">
                <img src="" alt="Jun" id="jun">
                <img src="" alt="Jul" id="jul">
                <img src="months-png/aug.png" alt="Aug" id="aug">
                <img src="months-png/sep.png" alt="Sep" id="sep">
                <img src="months-png/oct.png" alt="Oct" id="oct">
                <img src="months-png/nov.png" alt="Nov" id="nov">
                <img src="months-png/dec.png" alt="Dec" id="dec">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="date-section" id="date-section"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<nav class="nav" id="bottom-nav">
    <button id="left-button" class="left-b" onclick="leftb()"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
    <button id="right-button" class="right-b" onclick="rightb()"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    <div class="stamp" id="section-stamp">
        <span class="dot" id="dot-1"></span>
        <span class="dot" id="dot-2"></span>
        <span class="dot" id="dot-3"></span>
        <span class="dot" id="dot-4"></span> 
    </div>
    <button class="setting-b" id="settings-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i></button>
    <button id="add" class="add"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
</nav>
<style>
    body {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
   
    nav {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width:100%;
        height: 50px;
    }
    nav button{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #2d60ac;
        border-radius: 7px;
    }
    .setting-b {
        position: absolute;
        right: 55px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    .add {
        position: absolute;
        right: 2px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    i {
        color: white;
    }
    .clock {
        font-size: 200px;
        color: #2d60ac;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 13%;
        top: -7%;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .date {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #2d60ac;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20%;
        top: 55%;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    }
    .dot {
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        background-color: #bbb;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .stamp {
        position: absolute;
        top: 12.5px;
        left: 40%;
      }
      .noDisplay {
        display: none;
      }
</style>
<script>
    function updateClock() {
        const currentTime = new Date();
        var hours = currentTime.getHours();
        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        
        // Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros if needed
        minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
        seconds = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
        
        // Format the time as HH:MM:SS
        var timeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        
        // Update the clock text
        var clockElement = document.querySelector('.clock');
        clockElement.textContent = timeString;

        document.getElementsByClassName("date").innerHTML = currentTime.toDateString();
      }
      
      // Call the updateClock function every second
      setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
      
</script>
<script>
    dotnumb()
    var page = 0;
    function rightb() {
        if (page != 3) {
            page = page + 1
        } else {
            page = 3
            console.log("NO MORE Pages")
        }
    }
    function leftb() {
        if (page != 0) {
            page = page - 1
        } else {
            page = 0
            console.log("NO MORE Pages")
        }
    }

    function dotnumb() {
        if(page = 0) {
           document.getElementById('dot-1').style.width = '50px'
           document.getElementById('dot-2').style.width = '25px'
           document.getElementById('dot-3').style.width = '25px'
           document.getElementById('dot-4').style.width = '25px'
           page = 0
        }
        if(page = 1) {
            document.getElementById('dot-2').style.width = '50px'
            document.getElementById('dot-1').style.width = '25px'
            document.getElementById('dot-3').style.width = '25px'
            document.getElementById('dot-4').style.width = '25px'
            page = 1
        }
        if(page = 2) {
            document.getElementById('dot-3').style.width = '50px'
            document.getElementById('dot-1').style.width = '25px'
            document.getElementById('dot-2').style.width = '25px'
            document.getElementById('dot-4').style.width = '25px'
            page = 2
        }
        if(page = 3) {
            document.getElementById('dot-4').style.width = '50px'
            document.getElementById('dot-3').style.width = '25px'
            document.getElementById('dot-2').style.width = '25px'
            document.getElementById('dot-1').style.width = '25px'
            page = 3
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    const
    calenderSelect = document.querySelector('#calender-select')
  , calenderImgs   = document.querySelectorAll('#img-grp > img')
    ;
  
  showCalenderImg(); // first attempt.
  calenderSelect.addEventListener('change', showCalenderImg);
  
  function showCalenderImg()
    {
    calenderImgs.forEach( img => img.classList.toggle('noDisplay', img.id != calenderSelect.value ))
    }
</script>


you need to actually call the functions: $('#aug').hide() and so on for all of them

Could you describe very clearly what the problem is? Thanks.

added second answers code

(1) You're missing () at the end of your functions. e.g. $('#aug').hide should be $('#aug').hide(). Without these parentheses, the methods are not actually being executed, which is why you're not seeing any changes on the page.
(2) Hide everything but August at the beginning.
$('#aug').show();
$('#sep').hide();
$('#oct').hide();
$('#nov').hide();
$('#dec').hide();


Your logic doesn't hold water, clicking on the image of a month to make it appear alone doesn't really make sense, because you will no longer be able to make one of the other hidden months appear because they will no longer be clickable...
I think you are looking for something like this ?


const
  calenderSelect = document.querySelector('#calender-select')
, calenderImgs   = document.querySelectorAll('#img-grp > img')
  ;

showCalenderImg(); // first attempt.
calenderSelect.addEventListener('change', showCalenderImg);

function showCalenderImg()
  {
  calenderImgs.forEach( img => img.classList.toggle('noDisplay', img.id != calenderSelect.value ))
  }
.noDisplay { 
  display: none;
  }
<div class="page-1" id="page-1">
  <div class="calender" id="calender">
    <select id="calender-select">
      <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
      <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
      <option value="mar">Mar</option>
      <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
      <option value="may">May</option>
      <option value="jun">Jun</option>
      <option value="jul">Jul</option>
      <option value="aug">Aug</option>
      <option value="sep">Sep</option>
      <option value="oct">Oct</option>
      <option value="nov">Nov</option>
      <option value="dec">Dec</option>
    </select>
    <div id="img-grp" class="img-grp">
      <img src=""                   alt="Jan" id="Jan">
      <img src=""                   alt="Feb" id="Feb">
      <img src=""                   alt="Mar" id="mar">
      <img src=""                   alt="Apr" id="Apr">
      <img src=""                   alt="May" id="may">
      <img src=""                   alt="Jun" id="jun">
      <img src=""                   alt="Jul" id="jul">
      <img src="months-png/aug.png" alt="Aug" id="aug">
      <img src="months-png/sep.png" alt="Sep" id="sep">
      <img src="months-png/oct.png" alt="Oct" id="oct">
      <img src="months-png/nov.png" alt="Nov" id="nov">
      <img src="months-png/dec.png" alt="Dec" id="dec">
    </div>
  </div>




theres a drop down, idk if u noticed it

As mentioned in another answer, you're missing the () at the end of your .show() .hide() methods, so they are never called.
DRY = don't repeat yourself If you have to repeat code, there is a good chance that you can use a loop or function to not repeat yourself.
Also using javascript to mutate the DOM is considered "expensive". If you just need to update the appearance, you can do that via css.
Here we set the initial css of each <img> to display:none. Then there needs to be a css style rule corresponding with each month. When the user changes the selected month, it sets the data-month-selected property of the .calendar div to the month selected and the css style rules handle hiding and showing the correct <img>. This has the benefit of only requiring javascript to mutate one parent element, rather than every single <img> element. You could use this same method with your navigation system too.


let months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
//using loops to generate the DOM greatly reduces the size of the html file
$('.img-grp')
  .html(months.map((month) => `<img src="months-png/${month.toLowerCase()}.png" alt="${month}">`).join(''));

$('.calendar select')
  .html(months.map((month) => `<option>${month}</option>`).join(''))
  .on('change', function() {
    $('.calendar').attr('data-month-selected', this.value)
  });
//your provided code has a clock, here is a one-line clock
setInterval(() => $('.date').text((new Date()).toISOString().substr(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')), 1000);
.img-grp img { display:none; }

.calendar[data-month-selected="Jan"] .img-grp img[alt="Jan"],
.calendar[data-month-selected="Feb"] .img-grp img[alt="Feb"],
.calendar[data-month-selected="Mar"] .img-grp img[alt="Mar"],
.calendar[data-month-selected="Apr"] .img-grp img[alt="Apr"],
.calendar[data-month-selected="May"] .img-grp img[alt="May"],
.calendar[data-month-selected="Jun"] .img-grp img[alt="Jun"],
.calendar[data-month-selected="Jul"] .img-grp img[alt="Jul"],
.calendar[data-month-selected="Aug"] .img-grp img[alt="Aug"],
.calendar[data-month-selected="Sep"] .img-grp img[alt="Sep"],
.calendar[data-month-selected="Oct"] .img-grp img[alt="Oct"],
.calendar[data-month-selected="Nov"] .img-grp img[alt="Nov"],
.calendar[data-month-selected="Dec"] .img-grp img[alt="Dec"] { display: unset; }
<div class="page-1">
  <p class="date"></p>
  <div class="calendar" data-month-selected="Jan">
    <select></select>
    <div class="img-grp"></div>
  </div>
</div>
      
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



